# Postman i can not send json data

Tags: php, arrays, json, cakephp, postman

My JSON Data:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "dueDate": "2020-06-24T15:00:00",
        "lastStatusUpdateDate": "2020-06-24T10:36:53.593",
        "id": "5ef25338-dffc-2c00-01d8-dc1706060606",
        "name": "Tahsildaroglu Çeçil Peyniri 250 gr",
        "sku": "HBV00000NE0YY",
        "productImageUrlFormat": "https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/1/{size}/9541384503346.jpg",
        "quantity": 1,
        "merchantId": "ab28300e-c126-4e70-a483-9f3fe0e5f297",
        "totalPrice": {
            "currency": "TRY",
            "amount": 14.95
        },
        "unitPrice": {
            "currency": "TRY",
            "amount": 14.95
        },
        "customerName": "Ahmet Aslan",
        "CustomerId": "161dd81f-6097-4c18-9189-2225aee977e0",
        "status": "Delivered",
        "sapNumber": "000010",
        "dispatchTime": 0,
        "commission": {
            "currency": "TRY",
            "amount": 1.39
        },
        "paymentTermInDays": 32,
        "commissionType": 0,
        "cargoCompany": "HepsiJet",
        "customizedText01": "",
        "customizedText02": "",
        "customizedText03": "",
        "customizedText04": "",
        "customizedTextX": "",
        "creditCardHolderName": null,
        "isCustomized": false,
        "canCreatePackage": true,
        "isCancellable": false,
        "deliveryType": "AssignedDelivery",
        "deliveryOptionCode": "",
        "slot": {
            "id": null,
            "timeslot": "10:30-13:00"
        },
        "pickUpTime": "17:30 dummy",
        "discountInfo": [],
        "merchantSKU": "8691225154535",
        "purchasePrice": {
            "currency": "TRY",
            "amount": 0
        },
        "deptorDifferenceAmount": 0,
        "isJetDelivery": false
    }
]
}
```

[image: ss]

It returns => {"ms":"asd"}

[image: ss2]
If i send my json data from body>raw

It returns => []

In my Controller i try to catch this data like this =>

```
die(json_encode($_REQUEST));
```

How i can catch or send this json data ? I tried pre-request script but doesn't work or i can not wrote correctly.

Comment: Why would you `json_encode($_REQUEST)` again?

Comment: If you have DEBUG enabled you can just use `debug($this->request->getData())` to display you're POST requests body.